# Google search and restricted contents?

Tags: web-crawler, google-search

If a website has a content that will not be seen if someone is not logged in, then, how does Google see it?

The page is an e-commerce, restricted access (a user must log-in to see products) page; as such Google cannot see those products?

What would be the correct strategy to handle this problem?

Comment: Google only sees what the user sees without login in. It is against their policy to show different content.

Comment: are there any strategies to make google know that is a an ecommerce website?

Comment: What is the question here? Do you want Google to index the restricted areas or do you want to prevent it from doing it?

Comment: no, i want that google knows that it is an ecommerce website

Comment: That didn't answer the question. What should Google do with that information?

Comment: classify the website as ecommerce page

Comment: What does that have to do with indexing restricted areas?

Comment: the idea to make a restricted area, is: 1- knowing exactly who visited somepage, 2- if there is registeed users, then the server can candle that number since it is always inferior than a page that everyone can access to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of Google-Adsense this problem might make sense. Google provides site authentication feature for just this: see - [Google AdSense launches site authentication](http://searchengineland.com/google-adsense-launches-site-authentication-feature-11718)

You can provide google with your UserName & Password and google bot can crawl your protected pages - **so that it can serve targeted ads better when a visitor is on that page**.

Also - if this is not the intended purpose then please remember serving different content to Google from what is served to a user without username & password is blatantly wrong.
Imagine you searched for something on google and as soon as you clicked on the first link - and the website came up with a sign-up page and no useful information!!

Comment: yes, but it was the only trategy i found to know who visits the pages and to limit requests to the server (since only registred user will have access, then i can imagine how much the numbers of requests) because here in algeria the  bandwidth is limited

Comment: If the purpose is to only acquire information then you may use Google Analytics - it has detailed reports even in the free version.

Comment: ah, thank you, so i'll go with this, since what i want to do is just to let know google that the page is an e-commerce website.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the supplied User Agent header to detect whether the Google bot is visiting your site and handle it as if the bot is a regular user that is logged in. This is implemented in programs like phpBB (in that program as a special visibility option).

The drawback of the solution is that you cannot rely on the submitted User Agent header, because it is easy to send a crafted header so you appear, to the site, as being the Google bot (there are extensions eg. for Firefox that provide such functionality).

Comment: i use Tornado (python), yes this is a good idea, since i did this to catch the user agents and ignore some bots, so i can consider those coming from google bots as a registred users